# ASP.NET Dynamically Generated Linkbutton Click event not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a panel with its visibility set to false.  What I'm trying to do is dynamically create a LinkButton when my page is generated and have it so when I click the LinkButton, the panels' visibility gets set to true and it appears on my page.

I'm creating my LinkButton like so:

```
LinkButton _lb = new LinkButton();
_lb.Text = "Details";
_lb.Click += _lb_Click;
```

Here is the code for my LinkButton's Click event handlers:

```
protected void _lb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Panel1.Visible = true;
}
```

Whenever I render the page and click on the LinkButton, the event never fires.  I can put a break point inside the event handler and it never gets reached.  What am I missing?

EDIT:

I am adding the LinkButton to the page in a placeholder like so:

```
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(_lb);
```

EDIT2:

Thank you all for the replies so far.  It seems like the problem is definitely to do with the lifecycle.  To add details, the LinkButton is being created inside of a Timer_Tick event that is controlling the updating of an UpdatePanel.  I don't know how to create the LinkButton in Page_Load and pass it to the Timer_Tick event.  Any help?

Comment: How are you adding the linkbutton to the page, with just the code you have shown there will be nothing to click on.

Comment: Include the event handler which adds the LinkButton to the page.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  I edited my post to show how the LinkButton is getting added.

Comment: Check the page lifecycle - if you're trying to add the button too late in the rendering process, it won't be there.

Comment: At least here, your code works correctly. I literally pasted your code to my project and the link is rendered and the breakpoint's hit when `_lb_Click` is clicked. I create the `LinkButton` in `Page_Load`.

Comment: @BradL: In which event you are adding your link button ??

Comment: BradL is clicking on the LinkButton, which means that it's being rendered. Unless he creates the `LinkButton` at one point and then registers the event-handling method somewhere else.

Comment: Hi all, please see my latest edit. Thanks for the help so far!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't mention where it is, move your code to `Page_Load`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton _lb = new LinkButton();
    _lb.Text = "Details";
    _lb.Click += _lb_Click;
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(_lb);
}
```

Comment: From the post, you mention that the LinkButton is being rendered, so I assume that the page is being rendered correctly. Have you tried just adding the event handler (ie. `_lb.Click += _lb_Click;`) in Page_Load?